# Как правильно импортировать модуль

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3, python-import

Код и файл OWT_sqlite3 находятся в одной директории.

Сам код:

```
import sqlite3

from OWT_sqlite3 import *

conn = sqlite3.connect('vocabulary.db')

cur = conn.cursor()  
cur.execute('''create table if not exists vocabulary (word TEXT)''')

conn.commit()   

prompt = '''

1 - write a word

2 - see all vocabulary

q - exit
'''

actions = {

    "1": create,
    "2": select_all,
}

print(prompt)

while True:

    action = input('Enter choice: ')
    if action =='q':
        break
    elif action not in actions:
        print('Please, enter valid action ID')
    else:
        actions[action]()

cur.close()
```

Код подключаемого модуля OWT_sqlite3:

```
def create():
    """Add row in table"""
    global cur, con
    word = input('Please, enter word: ')
    tranclate = input('Please, enter tranclate: ')
    #finaly = '{} : {}'.format()

    cur.execute('''insert into vocabulary values(?)''', ('{} : {}'.format(word, tranclate)))
    conn.commit()

def select_all():    
    """Select all entries"""
    global cur
    cur.execute('select * from vocabulary')
    for row in cur:
        print(row)
    print()
```

Ошибка:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

~\0_Moduls\OWT_sqlite3.py in select_all()

     12     """Select all entries"""
     13     global cur
---> 14     cur.execute('select * from vocabulary')

     15     for row in cur:
     16         print(row)

NameError: name 'cur' is not defined
```

Как я понимаю cur  - локальная и оператор global в данном случае не поможет.
Вопрос в том, как верно подключить модуль OWT_sqlite3?
Насколько я знаю, нужно либо создать файл **init**.py в той же директории, либо прописать

`if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()`

Comment: Вы покажите где cur инициализирован?

Comment: cur = conn.cursor(),
4-я строка основного кода сверху

Comment: Код покажите),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: я его показал, взгляните на основной код. Cur - дескриптор файла, который можно использовать для выполнения операций над данными, хранящихся в базе данных.

Comment: в OWT_sqlite3 сделайте так from Сам код import cur

Comment: и передайте cur как параметр функции create и select_all

Comment: Вам в основном коде надо работать с потоком ввод вывод а базу подключать по мере необходимости

Comment: Пробуете ОПП стиль , очень удобно.

Comment: для импортируемого модуля создаётся своё глобальное пространство имён `globals`. Возможно в принципе явно передавать объекты в функцию импортируемого модуля. К примеру: определение функции `def select_all(cur): return cur` вызов функции `select_all(cur)`, но уж больно это начинает походить на ООП.